# XML Signature Validation

Tags: java, xml, x509

I have a problem that I can't figure out how to solve.
My application receives a (supposedly) signed XML and I have to validate if it is right.
Here's the signature part of what a receive in the XML

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="35121103220612000188550010000000131000009300">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>uLZ/66r6OoNLpj5v4cIsrv5zmyc=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>encoded</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>encoded</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
```

Everything I found on internet to validate needs the public key. But I don't have it. I have only the DigestValue.
Do you know if its possible to validate using only the DiggestValue?

Here's what I have so far. The problem is where to get the key for X509KeySelector

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("/home/test.xml");
    Node nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature").item(0);
    DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new X509KeySelector(publicKey), nl);
    XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    XMLSignature signature = factory.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
    System.out.println(signature.validate(valContext));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's in the KeyInfo section?  is it really "encoded" or something else?  my guess is that it contains the certificate that you need.

Comment: yes. i put encoded because its a big string. but it is an encoded string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the X509 key from the embedded X509 certificate.

UPDATE:

doing a google search for "xml signature x509certificate" turned up [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html), which would seem to give you all the answers you need.

Comment: @Haroldo The example link does not seem to be working.

Comment: I'm talking about the link itself.

Comment: Works from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html

Answer (score 4):

You may need to call setNamespaceAware(true) on your DocumentBuilderFactory, otherwise it will throw following exception:

```
Document implementation must support DOM Level 2 and be namespace aware
```

Answer (score 2):

The certificate itself contains the public key:

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificateStringFromXml));
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
PublicKey pk = cert.getPublicKey();
```